# Является ли возврат ссылки на уничтожаемый объект - UB?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Это UB?

```
const int& getValue() {
    return 1;
}


int main() {
    const int& a = getValue();
}
```

При инициализации константной ссылки литералом создается временный объект, область видимости, которого ограничивается ссылкой на этот объект. Получается что функция возвращает в caller ссылку на объект и сразу же уничтожается, получается переменная `a` инициализируется мусором?

Comment: @AlexGlebe Время жизни временного объекта, инициализированного 1, заканчивается при выходе из функции `The lifetime of a temporary bound to the returned value in a function return statement (8.7.3) is not extended; the temporary is destroyed at the end of the full-expression in the return statement.` и возвращенная ссылка уже битая.

Comment: @user7860670 получается я все верно описал?

Comment: Мне кажется, что да. Хотя надо разобраться, можно ли ссылку инициализировать невалидной ссылкой или UB будет только при разыменовании.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Возврат константной ссылки из функции не продлевает время жизни анонимного объекта.**

[Источник](https://habr.com/ru/post/669474/)

Comment: Из этого не следует наличие UB. Насколько я помню, пока ссылка не разыменовывается, неважно, что она протухла.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, да, но инициализироваться ссылка должна живым объектом. [dcl.ref / 5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.ref#5): `A reference shall be initialized to refer to a valid object or function.` Ссылка снаружи функции (`const int& a = getValue();`) пытается привязаться к объекту, время жизни которого подошло к концу, следовательно поведение не определено.

Answer (score 0):

Тут в любом случае возникает `-Wreturn-local-addr`, так что это не UB. Другой вопрос будет ли запускаться программа с таким предупреждением? Всё зависит от того, как используется статическая память во время выполнения вашей программы. Данные могут затереться, могут нет, но компилятор всё равно будет считать, что участок памяти уже не принадлежит какой-либо переменной. Поэтому, если после того как вы "инициализировали" `a`, вы выведете её содержимое, в некоторых случаях вы получите 1, а в некоторых пустой вывод.

Comment: Вообще как он будет жить это вопрос довольно спорный, потому что это опять же зависит от компилятора. Опять же, возвращаясь к тому же VS. Несмотря на то, что мы передаём ссылку на временный объект, который вроде как уже и жить то не должен, мы видим, что оказывается он ещё жив (попробуйте вывести потом `a`), хоть VS и выдаёт предупреждение.

Comment: С классами, согласен, это не работает. Но с встроенными типами данных возникает спорная ситуация.

Comment: Никакой спорной ситуации, в переменной будет так называемый мусор, т.к. ее память освобождена и может быть использована повторно.

Comment: проверил сам, точка с запятой не помогла, удалилась сразу. надо опять почитать доку. https://godbolt.org/z/heGEra95E

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков что значит освобождена, это статическая память, как она может быть освобождена? Если вы имели ввиду то, что данные затираются, то затираются ли они - зависит от компилятора.

Comment: Я имел ввиду как раз таки что данные не ОБЯЗАНЫ затираться(то что вы и наблюдаете, наличие вашей переменной) и участок памяти НЕ обязан НЕ использоваться(т.е. может быть использован а может и нет) в ДАЛЬНЕЙШЕМ(т.е. может быть затерт другой переменной). и сразу после ; - в переменной будет мусор =)

Comment: С этим согласен, добавлю уточнения по этому поводу в ответ.

Comment: `const int& df() {return 1 + 1;}` Что произойдет в этой ситуации? Как известно константная ссылка на объект rvalue имеет возможность продлевать его время жизни в соответствии с ссылкой. Здесь создается временный объект типа `int`, который будет присвоен ссылке и соответственно время жизни объекта будет продлено или вернётся ссылка уже на битый временный объект тк. время жизни временного объект ограничивается выражением.

Comment: `Тут в любом случае возникает -Wreturn-local-addr, так что это не UB` Как раз наоборот, такое предупреждение верный признак UB.